# Prove that if $f$ is increasing and it has a derivative at $x=a$ then $f '(a)\geq0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Part b of the question)

> If the conclusion of part (a) is changed to : $f'(a) > 0$, the statement becomes false.
>
> Indicate why the proof of part (a) fails to show that $f'(a) > 0$, and give a counterexample to the conclusion $f'(a) > 0$ (i.e., an example for which it is false).

My attempt:

For part a) A function is said to be increasing on a certain interval $x_1<a<x_2$ implies that $f(x_1)<f(a)<f(x_2)$. We want to calculate $f'(a)$, which is the slope of the tangent line to the curve $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$. The two sided limits exist because the function is differentiable at $x=a$. The derivative at $x=a$ is positive because the difference quotient is positive for both cases, $\delta x<0$ and $\delta x>0$.

In a) Is the derivative at $a$ equal to zero only if the function flattens out for values of $x$ near $a$.

In b) Will the statement fail to be true because the function contains an inflection point in its domain so we cannot say that it's increasing because its curve concaves to the left of x=a and concaves down to the right of x=a

Comment: Counterexample: $f(x) = x^3$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: I tried to edit your question to make it more readable, but you should check it - especially the last line

Comment: Modern terminology usually follows Nicolas Bourbaki: ... "$f$ is increasing" means  $x>y\implies f(x)\geq y$, and  "f is strictly increasing" means $x>y\implies f(x)>f(y).$..... Your last sentence is exactly the reason that $f'(x)$ may be zero for some $x$, even when $f $ is strictly increasing: The graph may flatten out at $x$, as in $f(x)=x^3$ at $x=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is increasing on $[x_1, x_2]$ then for an $a$ in that interval, if $f$ is differentiable there we have $$\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} \geqslant 0$$ since $f(a+h) - f(a) \geqslant 0$ for small $h > 0$ and $f(a+h) - f(a) \leqslant 0$ for $h < 0$, but $(f(a+h) - f(a))/h \geqslant 0$ regardless. The inequality is preserved when taking $h \to 0$. So $f'(a) \geqslant 0$

Comment: So this limit does preserve the weak inequality, f'(a)>=0, since it's possible that the function flattens out on some interval of x which accounts for the case of f'(x)=0.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>a$, then $f(x)>f(a)$ and so $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}>0$. Letting $x\to a$, we find $f'(a)\ge0$. Note that equality is possible - consider for example $f(x)=x^3$ and $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is increasing on $I$ and consider an interior
point $x_0$ of $I$.

For all $x ∈ I$ such that $x<x_0$, we have
$$f(x)−f(x_0) ≤ 0\quad and \quad x − x_0 < 0$$

Thus, the difference quotient $${Δf\overΔx}<0\quad for\,\,(x,x_0)$$

On the other hand, for any $x ∈ I$ with $x>x_0$,
$$f(x) − f(x_0) ≥ 0\quad and\quad x − x_0 > 0$$
Here too the difference quotient $${Δf\overΔx}\ge 0\quad\,\,for\quad (x_0,x)$$

Altogether,$${Δf\overΔx} = {f(x) − f(x_0)\over
x − x_0}≥ 0, ∀x \ne x_0$$

$$\lim_{x→{x_0}}{Δf\overΔx} = f(x_0)\quad yields\quad f(x_0) ≥ 0$$

As for the possible extremum points in $I$, we arrive at the same conclusion by considering one-sided limits of the difference
quotient, which is always  $≥ 0$.

Now Take $f \,\, with\,\, f'(x)\ge0$
The idea is to fix points $x_1 < x_2$ in $I$ and prove that $$f(x_1) ≤ f(x_2)$$
For that we use $$f(x_2)-f(x_1)=f'(\bar x)(x_2-x_1)$$
$$where\,\, \bar x\in(x_1,x_2)\,\, note\,that \quad f(\bar x) ≥ 0\,\,by\,\,assumption$$ But since
$$x_2 − x_1 > 0,\quad we\,\,have\quad f(x_2) − f(x_1) = f
(\bar x)(x_2 − x_1) ≥ 0$$
Considering $${f\quad such\,\,that\quad f'(x) > 0}\quad \forall \,\,x ∈ I$$ Now if $f$ is differentiable on $I$, the following logic equivalence holds:
$$f(x) ≥ 0, ∀x ∈ I \longleftrightarrow f\,\,\,is\,\, increasing\,\,on\,\, I$$
Furthermore,
$$f'(x) > 0, ∀\,x ∈ I ⇒ f\,\,\,is\,\,strictly\,\,increasing\,\,on\,\,I$$
The latter implication is not reversible:

$ f$ strictly increasing on $I$ does not imply
$f(x) > 0,$ $\forall\,\,x ∈ I$

We can observed that $f(x) = x^3$ is everywhere
strictly increasing, despite having vanishing derivative at the origin.

Comment: Treat $x_0$ as $a$